# Url manager и параметры

Tags: yii

```
$this->createUrl('controller/',array('param1'=>1))
```

Как привести

```
http://host.ru/index.php?r=controller&param1=1
```

к виду

```
http://host.ru/controller?param1=1
```

Comment: [руководство](http://www.yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/ru/final.url) читали?

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path', // формат: путь
    'showScriptName'=>false, // скрыть index.php
    'rules'=>array(
        // ключ: путь, что будет в урле, значение: какой экшен отрабатывает
        'pathName' => 'controllerName/actionName' 
    )
)
```

Во вьюшке:

```
<?= $this->createUrl('controllerName/actionName', array('param' => 'paramString')); ?>
```

на выходе:

```
/pathName?param=paramString
```

Comment: и что так для каждого контроллера и экшена прописывать???

Comment: @script_kid, никто не запрещает делать их универсальными. Вам подсказали как зделать так как вы хотите, а делать универсальные схемы будьте любезны сами, мы же о вашем проете ничего не знаем

Answer (score 0):

только наверное не

```
http://host.ru/controller?param1=1
```

а

```
http://host.ru/controller/param1/1
```

В конфиге прописать

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
 'rules'=>array(
             // тут настроить что нужно
        ),
```

и создать в корне сайта .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

На самом деле непонятно куда ты будешь посылать этот param1 в действие index? или в другое действие этого контроллера?

Больше инфы!

Comment: НЕТ ИМЕННО controller?param1=1

Comment: посылать этот param1 в действие index?

Comment: суть такова 

после включения url manager и создания htaccess

index action не присутствует в url, да он и не нужен 
http://host.ru/controller/notice/some_notice
а нужно что  было
после user/?notice=some_notice

как???

Comment: http://host.ru/controller/notice/some_notice
выдает ошибку notice не найден экшн
http://host.ru/controller//notice/some_notice
все отрабатывает номально, но хочется вида controller/?notice=some_notice типа как в вк http://vk.com/im?sel=100000