# URLmanager настройка

Tags: url, yii

Совсем не разобралась я что-то с urlmanager. Вот есть адрес:

> appt/index.php/appsinfo?id=61

как сделать чтобы он выводился следующим образом:

> appt/index.php/appsinfo/<имя дынных, которые в данный момент показаны на странице>

в конфиге такая картина:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```

.htaacess настроен

Comment: из этого
    appt/index.php/appsinfo?id=61
в это
    appstan/index.php/appsinfo/<имя дынных, которые в данный момент показаны на странице>

директория проекта различны. И проверьте правильно ли у файла .htaccess имя написано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну лучше вообще убрать **index.php** из пути, он там не нужен

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

А вообще на форуме куча подобных вопросов, они только по разному называются, но по тегу Yii находятся все

[Вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/209473/yii-url-manager-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=209475#209475)

Comment: все так. да не работает только( Даже index.php не пропал

Comment: rules сама писала? если да то они реально нужны или просто для примера взяты? и как ты пишешь URL на сайте с помощью чего?